# Creating a zip file with a timestamp

Tags: unix, shell, script, zip, date-time

I have been trying to create a script which compresses a directory with a timestamp and move it to another location on the same server, but I cant seem to get TESTDATE to display on the zip file, resulting in filed name .zip.

```
#!/bin/sh

# date
TESTDATE="date +%b-%d-%y"

# dirs to backups
DIRS="/volume1/NetBackup"

# Save zip file elsewhere on the server
DEST="/volume1/NetBackup/Backup"

# set to "no" keep old zip file and add new file
DELETE_OLD_ZIP_FILES="no"

#Path to binary files
BASENAME=/usr/bin/basename
ZIP=/usr/syno/bin/zip

for d in $DIRS
do
echo $DIRS
    zipfile="${DEST}/$(${TESTDATE} ${d} ${BASENAME}).zip"
    echo -n "Creating $zipfile..."
            # create zip file
                ${ZIP} -r $zipfile $d &>/dev/null && echo "Done!"
                done
```

Answer (score 5):

You have various problems there.

- First, you want to assign the result of the command `date  +%b-%d-%y` to the `TESTDATE` variable. To do so, you need to use [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) :

  ```
  TESTDATE=$(date  +%b-%d-%y)
  ```

  What your script is currently doing is assignig the string `date  +%b-%d-%y` to `TESTDATE`, not the result of the command. You can test by running this:

  ```
  TESTDATE="date +%b-%d-%y"
  echo $TESTDATE
  ```

  which will print `date +%b-%d-%y`.
- Second, you are using command substitution where you shouldn't, what you want is:

  ```
    zipfile="${DEST}/${TESTDATE} ${d} ${BASENAME}.zip"
  ```

  So, you don't want the parentheses. I also have no idea what you are trying to do with `basename` there. `basename` is a default program and you don't need to place it in a variable to use it. The command above sets zipfile to `/volume1/NetBackup/Backup/${TESTDATE} ${d} /usr/bin/basename` which is not a valid file name. If you explain what you're trying to do with basename I might be able to help but as it is it makes no sense.
- You seem to think that `DIRS` is a list, it's not, it is just the single directory `/volume1/NetBackup`.
- Another point is a matter of style. You should always avoid using CAPITAL variable names because environmental variables are all caps and this might lead to problems if you use the same name.

Anyway, *if* I understand what you're trying to do here, you could write the script like this (I have made `dirs` into an array since I think that's what you wanted):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# date
testdate=$(date +%b-%d-%y)

# dirs to backup
dirs=("/volume1/NetBackup" "/volume1/foobar")

# Save zip file elsewhere on the server
dest="/volume1/NetBackup/Backup"

# set to "no" keep old zip file and add new file
delete_old_zip_files="no"

#Path to binary files
zip=/usr/syno/bin/zip

base=$(/usr/bin/basename ${dest})
echo "bb $base";

for d in ${dirs[@]}
do
    ## I assume this is what you wanted to do, it will just
    ## return the name of the current $d directory
    base=$(/usr/bin/basename ${d})
    zipfile="${dest}/${testdate} ${base}.zip"
    echo -n "Creating $d $zipfile..."
    # create zip file
    ${zip} -r $zipfile $d  && echo "Done!" || echo ""
done
```

The example script above would create `/volume1/NetBackup/Backup/Mar-05-14 NetBackup.zip` and `/volume1/NetBackup/Backup/Mar-05-14 foobar.zip`. By the way, I would also strongly suggest you avoid creating file names with spaces, you'll thank me later.